# Reportviewer layout issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

I have a report viewer in with two different datasets and i have two different tables each table gets information from a dataset.

I would like the layout to be as the following for an example:

- Dataset 1 (Class)

  - Dataset 2 (Subclass)

My current reports returns all classes (from dataset 1) then shows the subclasses (from dataset 2) Is there a way in which i can show data from the two different datasets together?

I have two different Lists each referring to a dataset and within them are tables with the appropriate tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took the advice of others and combined both stored procedures into one and in the report viewer i used the filters feature to show different data in different tables.